# What is a good way to transfer files from linux to OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, file-transfer

I've been using Linux (mostly Ubuntu, but also Manjaro and Fedora) for over 10 years.  Lately I've toyed with the idea of moving to Mac OSX.  From what I've read, ext4 and HFS+ don't really talk well together.  Is there a 'relatively' efficient and painless way of transferring the linux files to OSX?

Comment: as far as I understand this question, there's **two** machines involved here: the (old) Linux machine and the (new) Mac OS machine, and they can run at the same time. Correct? Your question is a bit unclear on that.

Comment: Transfer files over the network with SSH, or store them in a `tar` archive on a USB drive formatted with some simple filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ftp, sshfs, scp, cifs/samba, rsync, netcat/nc, http (nginx/apache/`python3 -m http.server`) - just make sure you've checksummed all the files on both ends and hashes do match. All of them are supported under Mac and Linux.

Comment: I also found that I can copy the linux files to the cloud (e.g. Google or Dropbox) using rclone, then copy/move them from the cloud onto the mac.  Thanks for getting me started looking at this.